# How to modify plot axis ranges of a Ternary plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ternary

I am trying to create a ternary plot in R using the Ternary package. The range of points to be plotted is relatively restrained as you can see from the picture below.

I would like to rescale the triangle so that the `a-axis` (Al2O3) range is between 0 and 25 percent, the `b-axis` range (CaO+ MgO) between 40 and 60 percent and the `c-axis` range (SiO2) between 30 and 50 percent.

I would like to keep the shape of a triangle. My current plot command resumes to:

```r
library(Ternary)

TernaryPlot(alab = expression(bold('Al'[2]*'O'[3])), 
            blab = expression(bold('CaO + MgO')),
            clab = expression(bold('SiO'[2])))

TernaryPoints(data_ternary, col='blue', pch=15, cex=0.5)
```

[image]

```
data_ternary <- structure(c(13.6, 12, 9.61, 9.41, 12.9, 11, 48.23, 48.94, 47.3, 48.22, 45.72, 
                            48.04, 36.4, 36.6, 37.6, 37, 37.1, 35.6), .Dim = c(6L, 3L))
```

Comment: Can you share output of `dput(head(data_ternary))` with us?

Comment: Here is the output of dput(head(data_ternary)):                      structure(c(13.6, 12, 9.61, 9.41, 12.9, 11, 48.23, 48.94, 47.3, 
48.22, 45.72, 48.04, 36.4, 36.6, 37.6, 37, 37.1, 35.6), .Dim = c(6L, 
3L))

Comment: You could zoom in on the relevant part of the data with something like ` TernaryPlot(alab = expression(bold('Al'[2]*'O'[3])), 
            blab = expression(bold('CaO + MgO')),
            clab = expression(bold('SiO'[2])), 
   xlim=c(0.05,0.15), isometric=TRUE)`